# The meaning of the word "to" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/amJ-ev8Ial8). It is at around 5 minute and 53 second. Here is the context:

> People would down an entire pint **to** a pint and a half of saturated salt solution.

Does the speaker mean two pints and a half? if he does, would not it be simpler just to say two pints an a half?

Comment: I think you got it wrong. A pint to a pint and a half, is more likely.

Comment: Yes, **between** a pint and a pint and a half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means "between a pint and a pint and a half", or could also be written "1–1.5 pints".

Comment: +1 not only for the answer but for the proper use of an en dash to show the number range.